# urllib2/requests and HTTP relative path

Tags: python, urllib2, python-requests

How can I force urllib2/requests modules to use relative paths instead of full/absolute URL??

when I send request using urllib2/requests I see in my proxy that it resolves it to:

```
GET https://xxxx/path/to/something HTTP/1.1
```

Unfortunately, the server to which I'm sending it, cannot understand that request and gives me weird 302. I know it's in RFC, it just doesn't work and I'm tryign to fix it in python code. I don't have access to that server.

Relative path, works well

```
GET /path/to/something HTTP/1.1
Host: xxxx
```

So how can I force requests/urllib2 to not use absolute paths? and use simple relative paths?

Comment: Wouldn't `requests` need to know the domain in the first place to send it to? I guess I don't understand the question.

Comment: Please, post the full answer of your server/proxy thing

Answer (score 14):

Probably the following code would do for your case:

```
from urlparse import urljoin
import requests

class RelativeSession(requests.Session):
    def __init__(self, base_url):
        super(RelativeSession, self).__init__()
        self.__base_url = base_url

    def request(self, method, url, **kwargs): 
        url = urljoin(self.__base_url, url)
        return super(RelativeSession, self).request(method, url, **kwargs)

session = RelativeSession('http://server.net')
response = session.get('/rel/url')
```

Comment: In python3 the first import line needs to be changed to: `from urllib.parse import urljoin`

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a little bit of confusion here. As per [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-5.1) only *absolute path* or *absolute URI* are allowed in http request line. There is simply no such thing as *relative* http request -- as basicly http is stateless.

In your question you talking about *proxy*, that RFC state clearly that:

> The absoluteURI form is REQUIRED when the request is being made to a proxy.

As per se, AFAIK, your proxy is *not* HTTP/1.1 compliant. Is this a commercial product or an in-house development?

By the way, [HTTP 302](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302) is a redirect. Are you sure the ressource hasn't simply moved to an other location?

---

Anyway, by looking at the source code or *requests* ([requests/models.py L276](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/models.py#L276)) I'm afraid it doesn't seem to have any *easy* way to force the use of *absolute path*

My best bet would be to change the `PreparedRequest` object before it is send as described in [advanced usages/Prepared request](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#prepared-requests).