# Python requests - Session , define a default website for following relative url requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I would like to be able to do the following with the library `requests`

- Define a `Session` , with a default host defined
- from there, when using this `Session` with a relative path without domain, that it use this default host

something like that

```
session = requests.Session(default_host="http://mywebsite.com")
session.get("/login")
session.get("/page2")
```

the rationals behind:

- not have to repeat the same string everywhere
- changing the website (for local testing etc.) can be mapped to a variable

Is there something that can achieve that while still keeping the standard session object methods? (because of course I could wrap the session into an object, but then I will hide a lot of things)

Comment: I don't see anything in the docs about this.  Here's an answer that seems do what you want with a short and simple class: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28337825/3651127

Comment: @dagrha : awesome, exactly what I needed, thanks, you can post it as an answer , as I was not able to find it by googling

Comment: I'm glad that worked for you. Since the question is pretty similar to the one I linked to above, does it make sense to mark this one as a duplicate rather than provide the same answer?

Comment: @dagrha I don't know SO enough for that :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use a function to build your url?

The simplest solution that comes to my mind is

```
def build_url(page):
    return "http://mywebsite.com/" + page

session.get(build_url("login"))
```